# Filter Child Object of a Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, code-first

First of all, I'm new to the EF-code first and .NET in general.

Im working on a mobile web app thats being built with MVC4, EF, JQuery, AutoMapper & other technologies and libraries.

This might be confusing, but I will do my best to explain it right.

I have the following pocos:

```
  public class Test
{
    [Key]
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    .
    .
    Other properties
    .
    .
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserStatus> UserStatuses { get; set; }
}

public class UserStatus
{
    [Key]
    public int UserStatusId { get; set; }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    .
    .
    Other properties
    .
    .
}

public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    .
    .
    Other properties
    .
    .
}
```

and in my context class i have:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<CmeContext>(null);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
        .HasKey(a => new { a.TestId })
        .HasMany(s => s.Questions);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
        .HasKey(a => new { a.TestId })
        .HasMany(s => s.UserStatuses);          
}
```

The above Test object has a one-to-many relationship to Question and UserStatus objects through TestId. Each Test has it's own set of questions which are 4 questions per test, and 20 userStatuses 5 per question). 
As the name implies the UserStatus table has user statuses; it let me know which question(s) from what test was answered by a user.

The code in the controller:

```
var filtered = (from test in _ctxCmeContext.Test.Include("UserStatus").Include("Question")
                where test.Program == "SomeProgram" && test.IssueDate.Value.Year == year && test.IssueDate.Value.Month == monthNumber 
                orderby test.IssueDate descending 
                select new { test,
                                                 Questions = test.Questions, 
                         UserStatuses =     test.UserStatuses.Where(x => x.Customer == currentUserId) });
```

As you see I have an anonymous class so I can get the UserStatuses collection filtered by currentUserId to get the statuses for the current user only. Everything works fine at this point.

Here's what I need to do:

Each question needs to know its own status, so it's a one-to-one relationship between the Question and UserStatus table

In my context class I added the following:

```
      modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
     .HasRequired(x => x.UStatus)
     .WithOptional();
```

and in the Question Object I had:

```
                        public virtual UserStatus UStatus { get; set; }
```

and I also modified my linq statement as follows:

```
          var filtered = (from test in         _ctxCmeContext.Test.Include("UserStatus").Include("Question").Include("UStatus")
                where test.Program == "SomeProgram" &&   test.IssueDate.Value.Year == year && test.IssueDate.Value.Month == monthNumber 
                orderby test.IssueDate descending 
                select new { test, 
                             QuestionStatus =    test.Questions.Select(u=>u.UStatus), 
                             Questions = test.Questions, 
                             UserStatuses = test.UserStatuses.Where(x => x.Customer == currentUserId) });
```

The result:

the UStatus property had data for each question but it wasn't for the current user nor for the right test; it seemed to me that it just grabbed the first record it ecountered that had the same QuestionId from the Question table. No good.

so I changed the relationship to one-to-many:

In my context class I replaced:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
       .HasRequired(x => x.UStatus)
       .WithOptional();
```

with:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
           .HasKey(a => new { a.QuestionId })
           .HasMany(s => s.UStatus);
```

changed the UStatus property in the Question Object to:

```
   public virtual ICollection<UserStatus> UStatus { get; set; }
```

and removed the following from the linq statement

```
   QuestionStatus = test.Questions.Select(u=>u.UStatus),
```

This time I was able to get some correct data but only for the first 4 questions, and the rest were null

I don't know what to do anymore. Help me please.

Comment: Please try to explain it in short & sweet manner so that the question gets more attention. The more you write, less attention it gains. Just explain `what you have` and `what you want` along with your research effort(this one you can describe in words).

Comment: I'm just explaining what I have, what I did, and what I want to accomplish.All I want to do is to use the same filtered UserStatus collection so each question is aware of it's status.

Comment: What I wanted to point out is that, put the things in your question only which is absolutely necessary for the reader. Ex: You provided info regarding your `re-factoring` which simply increases the size of the question but not worth writing it. Psychologically speaking, people are lazy enough to read the things which doesn't worth reading it. However, I tried to answer my level best. Please check it.

Comment: go easy on whitespace... it doesnt make it more readable.  Just needs more mouse wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Question object I created a navigation property back to the Test object, and from there I was able to know the status of each question because the UserStatus is a child collection in the Test object.

Answer (score 0):

With the Schema/POCO you provided and by analyzing your story, what I can summarize is this:

```
You want to identify, which question(s) from what test was answered by a user?
```

If this is what you mean, then by assuming that `lazy loading` is `enabled in your context` I can suggest a query similar to this:

```
var questions = context.Questions.Where( q => q.Test.Program == "someProgram" 
                && q.Test.UserStatus.Any( us => us.UserId == currentUserId ));
```

It does the following:

1. Filter the questions which belongs to the Test `someProgram`
2. and having the `UserStatus` of the user `currentUserId`
3. Fetch the questions that satisfies this condition.

Hence in the `questions` collection you are having the answer for your problem.

My understanding of your problem might be wrong, but I believe it provides some hint to you.

Comment: lazy loading is disabled I don't want to return a list of Questions only. The list I need to return is a list of Tests (lets say 1 test) A test has 2 collections(UserStatus(4 records that are filtered by current user) & Questions(4 questions per test & each question needs to know its status from the same filtered UserStatus list)). I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, in that case, `Test` should contain all related `Questions` and `UserStatus` when filtered by user like `context.Tests.Where( t => t.UserStatus.UserId == currentUserId)`. I wrote the answer with lazy load enabled for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Thats not what I'm looking for but thanx anyway. I just took a different approach to it and got it to work.

Comment: Please post it as answer and accept it, so that others can benefit from it.